# Installing iruby behind a proxy failing at installing required msys2 packages

Tags: ruby, rubygems, msys2, iruby

I try to install iruby on my office computer, but it fails at "Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq" because it couldn't load the needed files with follwing error message: Failed to connect to mirrors.ustc.edu.cn port 443 after 10016 ms: Timeout was reached

Where can I set the proxy or how can I bypass this error?

I've already installed MSYS2, set the right proxy, updated MSYS2 and in it I installed mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq. When I attempt to install iruby I use PowerShell 7.4 in admin mode and enter following statement:

```
gem install iruby --http-proxy proxy.mycompany.de:port
```

Then I get those lines back and wait:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq
```

After a long time I get this output:

```
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.msys2.org übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10012 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.msys2.org übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.msys2.org port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von repo.msys2.org übertragen : Failed to connect to repo.msys2.org port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von repo.msys2.org übertragen : Failed to connect to repo.msys2.org port 443 after 10005 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.umd.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.umd.edu port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.umd.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.umd.edu port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.yandex.ru übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.yandex.ru port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.yandex.ru übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.yandex.ru port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von download.nus.edu.sg übertragen : Failed to connect to download.nus.edu.sg port 443 after 10004 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von download.nus.edu.sg übertragen : Failed to connect to download.nus.edu.sg port 443 after 10003 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.acc.umu.se übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.acc.umu.se port 443 after 10012 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.acc.umu.se übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.acc.umu.se port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.nluug.nl übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.nluug.nl port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.nluug.nl übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.nluug.nl port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.osuosl.org übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.osuosl.org port 443 after 10008 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.osuosl.org übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.osuosl.org port 443 after 10007 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.internet.asn.au übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.internet.asn.au port 443 after 10002 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.internet.asn.au übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.internet.asn.au port 443 after 10001 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.selfnet.de übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.selfnet.de port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.selfnet.de übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.selfnet.de port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.dotsrc.org übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.dotsrc.org port 443 after 10016 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.dotsrc.org übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.dotsrc.org port 443 after 10015 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn port 443 after 10003 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn port 443 after 10002 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn port 443 after 10005 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn port 443 after 10004 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.ustc.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.ustc.edu.cn port 443 after 10016 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.ustc.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.ustc.edu.cn port 443 after 10015 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.nju.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.nju.edu.cn port 443 after 10013 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.nju.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.nju.edu.cn port 443 after 10004 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von repo.extreme-ix.org übertragen : Failed to connect to repo.extreme-ix.org port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von repo.extreme-ix.org übertragen : Failed to connect to repo.extreme-ix.org port 443 after 10005 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.hit.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.hit.edu.cn port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.hit.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.hit.edu.cn port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.clarkson.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.clarkson.edu port 443 after 10012 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.clarkson.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.clarkson.edu port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von quantum-mirror.hu übertragen : Failed to connect to quantum-mirror.hu port 443 after 10008 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von quantum-mirror.hu übertragen : Failed to connect to quantum-mirror.hu port 443 after 10008 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.archlinux.tw übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.archlinux.tw port 443 after 10007 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.archlinux.tw übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.archlinux.tw port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von fastmirror.pp.ua übertragen : Failed to connect to fastmirror.pp.ua port 443 after 10006 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von fastmirror.pp.ua übertragen : Failed to connect to fastmirror.pp.ua port 443 after 10005 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.ufro.cl übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.ufro.cl port 443 after 10016 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.ufro.cl übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.ufro.cl port 443 after 10015 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.cc.uoc.gr übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.cc.uoc.gr port 443 after 10002 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von ftp.cc.uoc.gr übertragen : Failed to connect to ftp.cc.uoc.gr port 443 after 10002 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.jmu.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.jmu.edu port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.jmu.edu übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.jmu.edu port 443 after 10013 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in port 443 after 10001 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in port 443 after 10000 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von www2.futureware.at übertragen : Failed to connect to www2.futureware.at port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von www2.futureware.at übertragen : Failed to connect to www2.futureware.at port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn port 443 after 10015 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn port 443 after 10014 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.bit.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.bit.edu.cn port 443 after 10011 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.bit.edu.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirrors.bit.edu.cn port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.aliyun.com übertragen : Connection timeout after 10010 ms
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.aliyun.com übertragen : Connection timeout after 10009 ms
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.iscas.ac.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.iscas.ac.cn port 443 after 10010 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirror.iscas.ac.cn übertragen : Failed to connect to mirror.iscas.ac.cn port 443 after 10009 ms: Timeout was reached
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.cloud.tencent.com übertragen : Connection timeout after 10004 ms
Fehler: Konnte Datei 'mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any.pkg.tar.zst' nicht von mirrors.cloud.tencent.com übertragen : Connection timeout after 10003 ms
Warnung: Konnte einige Dateien nicht übertragen
Fehler: Der Vorgang konnte nicht durchgeführt werden (Fehler in der Bibliothek für Downloads)
pacman failed with the following output:
Abhängigkeiten werden aufgelöst …
Nach in Konflikt stehenden Paketen wird gesucht …

Pakete (2) mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3

Gesamtgröße des Downloads:             0,62 MiB
Gesamtgröße der installierten Pakete:  3,86 MiB

:: Installation fortsetzen? [J/n]
:: Pakete werden empfangen …
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq-4.3.5-3-any wird heruntergeladen …
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libsodium-1.0.19-2-any wird heruntergeladen …
Fehler sind aufgetreten, keine Pakete wurden aktualisiert.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing iruby:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/iruby-0.7.4/ext
C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/ruby.exe -rrubygems C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/exe/rake RUBYARCHDIR\=C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/iruby-0.7.4 RUBYLIBDIR\=C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/iruby-0.7.4
Unable to load this gem. The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be found.
If this is a Windows platform, make sure libzmq.dll is on the PATH.
If the DLL was built with mingw, make sure the other two dependent DLLs,
libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll and libstdc++6.dll, are also on the PATH.
For non-Windows platforms, make sure libzmq is located in this search path:
["C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.7/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/../../ext/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\msys64\\usr\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Ruby33-x64\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\Scripts\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\Python312\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\Scripts\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jre-8.0.222.10-hotspot\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jre-8.0.222.10-hotspot\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Oracle\\32\\product\\19.0.0\\client_1\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Oracle\\64\\product\\19.0.0\\client_1\\bin/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Windows\\system32/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Windows/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Citrix\\HDX\\bin\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\Citrix\\HDX\\bin\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\sqlite3/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Shell 8.0\\bin\\/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Users\\GablerAnAdm\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps/libzmq.dll", "C:\\Users\\GablerAnAdm\\.dotnet\\tools/libzmq.dll", "C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/libzmq.dll", "/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dll", "/opt/local/lib/libzmq.dll", "/usr/lib64/libzmq.dll"]
rake aborted!
Failed to install ZeroMQ


Caused by:
LoadError: The libzmq library (or DLL) could not be loaded (LoadError)
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:132:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:132:in `rescue in require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:126:in `require'

Caused by:
LoadError: Could not open library 'C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/ffi-rzmq-core-1.0.7/lib/ffi-rzmq-core/../../ext/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
 (LoadError)
.
Could not open library 'C:\Ruby33-x64\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64\usr\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Ruby33-x64\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\Python312\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\Python311\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.222.10-hotspot\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-8.0.222.10-hotspot\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Oracle\32\product\19.0.0\client_1\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Oracle\64\product\19.0.0\client_1\bin/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Windows\system32/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Windows/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Windows\System32\Wbem/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\HDX\bin\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\Citrix\HDX\bin\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\sqlite3/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Users\GablerAnAdm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:\Users\GablerAnAdm\.dotnet\tools/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library '/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library '/opt/local/lib/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library '/usr/lib64/libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'libzmq': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Could not open library 'libzmq.dll': Failed with error 126: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

.
Searched in <system library path>, /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, /opt/local/lib
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:132:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:132:in `rescue in require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:126:in `require'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ffi-rzmq (LoadError)
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
<internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
Tasks: TOP => default => all => ensure_zeromq
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/iruby-0.7.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/iruby-0.7.4/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Ruby comes with an integrated MSYS2/MINGW extansion (C:\Ruby33-x64\msys64) which I should have used, and now did, instead of an own MSYS2 installation (C:\msys64). There I added the proxy settings, updated MSYS/MINGW and installed mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-zeromq.